# Solve $y^2 = x^3 - 4$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Solve $y^2 = x^3 - 4$

So far i've tried to look at this:

$x^3 = (y-2i)(y+2i)$.

I think we need to prove that $y+-2i$ are coprime, so suppose not then:

$d = u+iv$ divides both numbers. So also d divides the sum and difference: $d|2y$ and $d|4i$.

If one applies the euclidean norm function we get that $u^2 + v^2|4y^2$ and $u^2 + v^2|16$.

And here i get stuck, any tips?

Kees

Comment: What are $x, y$, integers?

Comment: yes of course, sorry i should have mentioned that.

Comment: They aren't generally coprime, so you will have a hard time proving it. For example, $y=2$ gives a solution. But they will be coprime when $y$ is odd since and common divisor is a common divisor of $4i$,  $4i$ only has divisors $1+i,1-i$, and $y+2i$ is not divisible by either when $y$ odd. When $y$ even, you are stuck. Might be possible to prove directly that $y=2$ is the only solution there.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1073542/solve-y2-x3-4-in-x-y-in-mathbbz?rq=1

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, is it obvious that when y is odd, the terms are co-prime? I don't see it very specifically can you explain please? :)

Comment: I've already outlined why when $y$ odd. What did I miss? Do you see why any common factor must divide $4i$? The only prime factor of $4i$ is $i+1$. But $1+i$ divides $2i$, and it does not divided $y$, so it cannot divided $y+2i$. @KeesTil

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, it is the first part. I thought that out of the equation $u^2 + v^2 = 16$ we get the divisors $\{+-1,+-2,+-4,+-i,+-2i,+-4i,+-(1+-i),+-(2+-i)\}$. I don't see how you've shortened it to so few divisors

Comment: Another solution: $(x,y)=(5,11)$.

Comment: No idea what you are saying. "The first part." Be specific and direct. $4i =-i (1+i)^4$ so the only **prime** factor of $4i$ is $1+i$ (and its various associates, $\pm1 \pm i$.) Also, use `\pm` for $\pm$ and your text is more readable.

Comment: nice thanks for your help i am almost there :)

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1520668/how-to-solve-the-following-mordell-equation-y2-x3-3/1520681#1520681) again for the excellent notes on Mordell's equation $y^2=x^3-c$ by K. Conrad.

Comment: In 1998 $y^2=x^3+k, k\in\Bbb Z_{\neq 0}$ was fully solved for all $|k|\le 10^4$ ([this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1000281602647), can be found e.g. [here](http://www.inf.unideb.hu/~pethoe/cikkek/67_MORDELL.pdf); full lists of solutions are [on OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=mordell&language=english&go=Search)).

Comment: Full solution [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf) (page $6$).

Answer (score 1):

Your computation are done in the ring of Gaussian integers, which is a PID. Let $p$ be a prime in this ring dividing both $y+2i$ and $y-2i$. Then $p$ divides $2y$ and $4i$, so it is $1+i$ (up to invertible elements), because this is the only prime dividing $2$.

From $(1+i)(h+ki)=y+2i$ we get $h-k=y$, $h+k=2$, so $h=(2+y)/2$, $k=(2-y)/2$ and $y$ must be even.

So the two elements are indeed coprime if $y$ is odd. In this case $y+2i$ must be a cube times an invertible element, so
$$
y+2i=u(a+bi)^3
$$
In the case $u=1$, we get $y=a(a^2-3b^2)$, $2=b(3a^2-b^2)$. Since $y$ is odd, $a$ must be odd and $b$ even. Thus $b=\pm2$ and $3a^2-4=\pm1$. The only case is $b=-2$, $a=\pm1$. So $y=\pm11$.

**A solution has been found: $x=5,y=\pm11$.**

In the case $u=i$, we get $y=-b(3a^2-b^2)$, $2=-a(a^2-3b^2)$. So $b$ must be odd and $a$ even. Therefore $a=\pm2$. If $a=2$ we get $4-3b^2=-1$ (no solution). If $a=-2$ we get $4-3b^2=1$, so $b=\pm1$. This corresponds to $y=\pm11$, the same as before.

The cases $u=-1$ and $u=-i$ are the same, because the minus sign can be merged with the cube.

---

Suppose $y$ is even. Then also $x$ must be even and so we can set $x=2X$ and $y=2Y$, obtaining
$$
2X^3=Y^2+1=(Y+i)(Y-i)
$$
Since $1+i$ is prime and divides the left-hand side, it must divide $Y+i$ or $Y-i$. From $(1+i)(h+ki)=Y+i$ we get $h-k=Y$ and $h+k=1$. Thus $h=(Y+1)/2$ and $Y$ must be odd. Similarly, if $1+i$ divides $Y-i$. If we set $Y=2Z+1$, we get
$$
\frac{2Z+1+i}{1+i}=Z+1-Zi,
\qquad
\frac{2Z+1-i}{1-i}=Z+1+Zi.
$$
and the equation can be written as
$$
X^3=(Z+1-Zi)(Z+1+Zi)
$$
A prime dividing both factors must divide $2(Z+1)$ and $2Zi$. If it divides $Z$, it cannot divide $Z+1$, so it divides $2$. So the only prime that can divide both numbers is $1+i$. However, from
$$
(1+i)(h+ki)=Z+1+Zi
$$
we get $2h=2Z+1$, a contradiction. So the two factors are coprime and therefore they are cubes times an invertible.

Case $Z+1+Zi=(a+bi)^3$. We get $Z+1=a(a^2-3b^2)$ and $Z=b(3a^2-b^2)$.
Therefore $a^3-3ab^2-3a^2b+b^3=1$, or $(a+b)(a^2-4ab+b^2)=1$.

From $a+b=1$ we get $(a+b)^2-6ab=1$, hence or $6ab=0$. Thus $a=0$ or $b=0$ and we get the solutions $a=0$, $b=1$, that is $Z=-1$; $a=1$, $b=0$, that is $Z=0$. This corresponds to $Y=-1$ and $Y=1$.

From $a+b=-1$ we get $-6ab=-2$, that has no solution.

Case $Z+1+Zi=i(a+bi)^3$. $Z+1=-b(3a^2-b^2)$ and $Z=a(a^2-3b^2)$. Here we get $-a^3-3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3=1$, so $(b-a)(a^2+4ab+b^2)=1$ The case $b-a=1$ forces $6ab=0$. The case $b-a=-1$ forces $6ab=2$. Thus we don't find new solutions.

**Another solution has been found $x=2$, $y=\pm2$**

**No other solutions exist**

Comment: Shouldn't you get $h-k=Y$, not $h-k=1$? The rest of your argument falls apart after that error (for $y$ even.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Please, check again, I think I have fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Consider

$y^2 - 4 = x^3 - 8$

$(y - 2)(y + 2) = (x - 2)(x^2 + 2x + 4)$

y = 2, x = 2 is a solution.  So that's a start.